# Does Django logs usernames internally

Tags: python, django, logging

All..

I have a Django site and to access it all the users have to go through the login page.

My question is when a user is given a access through the login page to enter the site.Does Django logs the username in any of the Django internal tables....

Thanks.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `last_login` column of the user's record in table `auth_user` is updated with the date/time of the successful login.